# Parameter count mismatch trying to execute login method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I have an issue with parameters, I suppose to check the Application Login if it set to true, then execute the method LoginFirst, but every time I try to execute the test I got this error:

```
Message: Test method AppNameWebMultiMap.Bader.DeleteDomain.DeleteDomainTest threw exception: 
System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
```

Here is the method:

```
[TestMethod]
private void LoginFirst()
{
    var login = new AppLogin();
    login.AppLoginBySaTest();
}
```

Here is the how I execute it:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void DeleteDomainTest(bool loginFirst = true)
    {
        //Login 
        if (loginFirst)
        {
            LoginFirst();
        }
    //Execute delete domains function

    }
```

The method DeleteDomainTest do the following:
First login
then attempt to delete domains.

Comment: How do you call `DeleteDomainTest`? Why do you have `TestMethod`, are you unit testing?

Comment: The `//Execute delete domains function` - does that use reflection at all? there's two possibilities here: some code you aren't showing is using reflection and making a mess of it, or: the test framework *itself* is using reflection (perhaps to execute `DeleteDomainTest`), and expects that method to be parameterless; are you sure the `[TestMethod]` isn't on `DeleteDomainTest`? I would fully understand if the test framework wants test method like `DeleteDomainTest` to be parameterless. The `.StackTrace` would be useful here. Or... just telling us which line is throwing.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I use CodedUI testing, The [Test Method] here will call the DeleteDomainTest method when I run the test.

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes why would `[TestMethod]` run `DeleteDomainTest`? It is on `LoginFirst`, and `LoginFirst` doesn't call `DeleteDomainTest` - rather: `DeleteDomainTest` calls `LoginFirst`

Comment: @MarcGravell The other code does not refelect with the login method at all, I can run it without it if I logged already, I should mention that it was working normally before, it do not know what I done wrong

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes you've completely ignored my questions every time. Please: look at the questions I've asked you. I'm asking them *to try to help you*.

Comment: @MarcGravell Sorry I do not ignore your question and I am glad that are helping :) , for the [TestMethod] I added to the code above , it already exists on the code, sorry.

Comment: Right; so with the edit: is it as simple as the test framework wants the `DeleteDomainTest` method to be parameterless, but it has a parameter? Try *taking away the parameter* and see if it works. If that doesn't fix it, then the problem is in code that you aren't showing us

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes its working without the Parameter , but I need that Parameter to switch login on/off, because the "Delete domain function" can be accessed by other methods in the application, So If I already logged in Creating Domain method in the application, I do not want to login again in Delete Domain method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, the problem here is that the method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteDomainTest(bool loginFirst = true) {...}
```

is marked as a test method (via the attribute), and has a parameter, with the reason for the parameter being that it is used from "other methods in the application". The test framework wants the test method to be parameterless.

This suggests a fundamental misapplication of test methods. If a method is used by other code, then **it isn't a test method**. Test methods should always be standalone and top-level. You should be able to resolve this simply by refactoring slightly:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteDomainTest() { DeleteDomainImpl(); }

internal void DeleteDomainImpl(bool loginFirst = true) {...}
```

Now we have a `DeleteDomainImpl` method that can be used from other tests as required, and a `DeleteDomainTest` that actually is the test that runs it in this case - using the default parameters.